# A newbie question about action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, itemrenderer

I saw someone using label as an ItemRenderer for DataGrid, the code is here.
I just don't understand 
1）what is the "@" mean here : "data.@price"
2）what is the type of "data" and how could I use it?
in order to understand this, what keyword should I search for?

```
package {
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.*;

    public class PriceLabel extends Label {

        private const POSITIVE_COLOR:uint = 0x000000; // Black
        private const NEGATIVE_COLOR:uint = 0xFF0000; // Red

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            /* Set the font color based on the item price. */
            setStyle("color", (parseFloat(data.@price) <= 0) ? NEGATIVE_COLOR : POSITIVE_COLOR);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Adobe operators reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#attribute_identifier):

> Identifies attributes of an XML or
>   XMLList object. For example, myXML.@id
>   identifies attributes named id for the
>   myXML XML object. You can also use the
>   following syntax to access attributes:
>   myXML.attribute("id"), myXML["@id"],
>   and myXML.@["id"]. The syntax
>   myXML.@id is recommended. To return an
>   XMLList object of all attribute names,
>   use @*. To return an attribute with a
>   name that matches an ActionScript
>   reserved word, use the attribute()
>   method instead of the @ operator.